# "The target can't handle this type of document" move to custom virtual folder

Tags: windows, visual-c++, explorer

I have some code in VC++ that create windows explorer shell integration and shows some remote database folders in windows explorer as native folders. When I use "move to folder..." from the explorer menu and move some file to that virtual folder, windows give me error message "The target can't handle this type of document", even though the shell integration successfully moves the file to the database.

I am not able to find out what is the cause of that error and how to disable the same from my code, what configuration is needed.

Does anyone has an idea about the same.

Comment: How do you implement copy/move operation? Via IDropTarget or via ITranserDestination? I created simple NSE with IDropTarget and when I select my NSE as target in Move to (from Ribbon pane) shell just calls my IDropTarget.Drop method and does not show any message.

Comment: I have not written the original code, just doing bug fixing. But searching the code I see IDropTarget implementation.

Comment: Could you show IDropTarget::DragEnter and IDropTarget::Drop methods? I am interesting in logic of processing of pdwEffect value.

Comment: pdwEffect  is DROPEFFECT_MOVE in DragEnter and in the Drop method it is set to DROPEFFECT_NONE before calling release method at the end. Tried keeping it DROPEFFECT_MOVE only in the Drop method before release, but doesn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, Drop was returning hr instead of S_OK. the hr value came from some other method call and was wrongly returned as something else instead of S_OK.
It just in one of the if condition, the original developer has forgotten to set the hr value correctly. normally hr values are not used, it just for storing the result of a method call and returning the same at the end, so its very hard to figure what is wrong, because all methods are working properly.
These silly mistakes are hard to find, though easy to fix.
Thanks Denis for pointing where to look.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was not being able to move or copy anything to my pictures on my computer. The only thing I could do was go to C: and click on my user, change the name of My Pictures to something like My Picturess, restart the computer. You can also pin a new folder to quick assess for the the folder you're having a problem with.
My answer is just to the question, "The target can't handle this kind of document that so many are having a problem finding a solution to."

Comment: You are not answering the question in its actual context. Because you changed the context of the question for yourself, you are actually answering a different question than was asked.